# For any Borel $\mu$ on $[0,1]^d$, show there exists $C>0$ and $x \in [0,1]^d$ such that $\mu(B(x,r)) \geq C r^ d$ for all $r>0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu:\mathcal{B}([0,1]^d) \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a Borel probability measure on $[0,1]^d$, where $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $[0,1]^d$ is endowed with the standard Euclidean metric. I'm trying to show that there must exist $x \in [0,1]^d$ and $C>0$ such that for all $r>0$
$$\mu(B(x,r)) \geq Cr^ d.$$
I can get the proof to work when $d=1$, but am stuck on the general case.

For $d=1$ the proof is as follows. Suppose not. Let $C<1$. Then for all $x \in [0,1]$ there exists $r_x>0$ such that
$$\mu(B(x,r_x)<C r_x.$$
By compactness we can take a finite set $S \subset [0,1]$ such that $\cup_{x \in S} B(x,r_x) \supseteq [0,1]$. Note, by making $S$ smaller if necessary, we may assume that $\sum_{x \in S} 2r_x \leq 2$. To see this, observe that if three intervals have non-empty intersection, then their union is equal to the union of just two of these intervals (it is this step that I cannot get to work when $d>1$). Hence,
$$1 \leq \sum_{x \in S} \mu(B(x,r_x)) \leq C \sum_{x \in S} r_x \leq C <1,$$
which is a contradiction.

Any help is appreciated. I'm sure this is in a textbook somewhere, but haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Since posting I found a proof.

Note that the condition that there exists $x \in [0,1]^d$ and $C>0$ such that for all $r>0$
$$\mu(B(x,r)) \geq Cr^ d,$$
can be replaced with the obstensibly weaker condition that there exists $x \in [0,1]^d$ and $C>0$ such that for all $r>0$ sufficiently small
$$\mu(B(x,r)) \geq Cr^ d$$
(since if this holds, we can take $C>0$ to be smaller so that the original condition holds).

The result can now be proved using Lebesgue's decomposition theorem, the Radon–Nikodym theorem, and Lebesgue's differentiation theorem.